# Grid Filter not submitting param values

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a basic grid, and I have added some filters to columns. I added them in the constructor like so, since some of them use stores

```
constructor: function(config) {
        Ext.apply(this, {
            features : [{
                ftype: 'filters',
                encode: true,
                local: false,
                filters: [{
                    type: 'string',
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                },{
                    type: 'string',
                    dataIndex: 'priority'
                },{
                    type: 'list',
                    store: Ext.getStore('adminCategory'),
                    dataIndex: 'adminOrg',
                    labelField: 'displayName'
                },{
                    type: 'list',
                    store: Ext.getStore('adminClientList'),
                    dataIndex: 'client',
                    labelField: 'name',
                    listeners: {
                        activate: function(obj, eOpts) {
                            console.log(obj);
                        }
                    }
                }]
           }]
      });
      this.callParent(arguments);
```

The menu items load just fine, however when the filter activates, and starts to load the store, the filter params are not present, so they aren't submitted to the server.

I checked the `beforeload` event on the store, and the `filters` array is empty (in the operations object where all the sorter info is stored too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filtersfeature` doesn't store the filter info in the same place as the default filters go. I don't know why, but it doesn't. In the same object you found the `filters` and `sorters` arrays, look in the `params` property, there should be a property in `params` called `filter`. That will contain the filters. By default, I believe all the filters are encoded into a json string, so if you want them as an array, you'll have to use `Ext.decode`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing. I checked the `params` property as well. Nothing in there about filters. Here it is. Wondering if this is a new bug in version 4.2.1: 
`params: Object
limit: 25
page: 1
sort: "[{"property":"priority","direction":"ASC"}]"
start: 0`

Comment: The relevant code for 4.2.1 looks the same as 4.2. Are you sure a filter is active when the server call is performed?

Comment: Perhaps it is being sent down to the server. You said you are checking the `beforeload` event on the store. There is a handler for that event in the `FiltersFeature`, and that is when the filter data is stuffed in. Perhaps you are catching it before the `onBeforeLoad` method is called in `FiltersFeature`?

Here is the source, btw. You can access it from the ExtJS docs. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/source/FiltersFeature.html#Ext-ux-grid-FiltersFeature

Comment: I am checking the request in Chrome dev tools, and have breakpoints setup on the PHP server side (testing localhost), so it's confirmed the filter params aren't being sent. You are correct though, `onBeforeLoad` in `FiltersFeature` is called after the store event. And I see my filters present there in the `params` field, the FIRST time. For some reason `onBeforeLoad` in `FiltersFeature` is called three times, when the store's `beforeload` is called only once. The 2nd and 3rd time it's called, the params are empty.

Comment: Hmm, that is very odd. I'm not sure I can help you much more. I know the `FiltersFeature` does some pretty odd and inefficient stuff, so much so that I rewrote most of it to improve it for my application (including the part that serializes the filter data to be sent to the server). If you can get a fiddle working that recreates this bug, I could try tweaking it to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I am going to see if I can step through the trace to figure out what's causing it to be called 3 times. I will report back regardless, but give you all the credit since you helped me get here.

Comment: AHA. I have a tab panel that has the same instance of this grid (3 tabs). So it is trying to grab the filters for each grid instead of just on the active tab. Now I just have to figure out how to get the FiltersFeature to only fire on the grid that is actually displayed on screen (in the active tab).

Comment: I would just have a separate instance of the grid for each tab. Is there a reason you have them all use the same instance? If you don't already, you can just create your grid as a new component that extends the `Ext.grid.Panel`, and then it is easy to reuse that grid in different places.

Comment: I assumed they were all separate instances. I don't use Ext.create though. in the Ext.define('MyTabPanel'); the items array just uses the custom xtype I defined. I am guessing it's not creating 3 instances? I am trying extending the FiltersFeature class to only apply params if it's not empty to see if that works.

Comment: Using the xtype should still create separate instances.

Comment: Maybe that's a bug in the FiltersFeature. Adding this statement to see if it helps in the onBeforeLoad `if (params.filter != undefined) {
            Ext.apply(options.params, params);
        }`